# Autodesk-Forge configurator live sample with geometry change

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to build enterprise solution for configurator base on Autodesk Inventor models and drawings. I want to have ability to change dimension of assembly (witdh, depth, length and another). I want to see changes on model in real time (something like here but with changes dimensions in custom values: https://tylko.com/shelf/bookcases/1429438/?cv=0&board=cat_all__type_all__id_4267)

As a result I want to have fully documented model with drawings.

Can Forge do that? Is there any demo?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, here's a sample application that does something similar.
https://forge-rimconfigurator-inventor.herokuapp.com/

You can find the source code of the above application here:
https://github.com/sajith-subramanian/forge-rimconfigurator-inventor

There also is another intricate sample available. You can find it here:
http://inventor-config-demo.autodesk.io/

The source code of the above sample is available here:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor

Comment: Thank you for response. Provided samples are different than: https://tylko.com/shelf/bookcases/1429438/?cv=0&board=cat_all__type_all__id_4267

My sample is dynamic. Is there a possibility to not wait for change update. Same as you can see change directly in Inventor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response. Provided samples are different than:
https://tylko.com/shelf/bookcases/1429438/?cv=0&board=cat_all__type_all__id_4267

My sample is  dynamic. Is there a possibility to not wait for change update. Same as you can see change directly in Inventor.